# Change comma seperated null checks to include column name

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have been looking at this for a while and can't figure it out.

Currently I have a **dynamic** list of comma seperated strings like the following:

```
tech,class
```

I currently have the following null checks in my query, which is dynamically generated:

```
ISNULL([tech], 0),ISNULL([class], 0)
```

How can I change it so I can keep the column names? Like the following:

```
ISNULL([tech], 0) as tech,ISNULL([class], 0) as class
```

**Edit**

I am changing the categories like this:

```
DECLARE @categories NVARCHAR(MAX), @fields NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @categories = COALESCE(@categories+',','')+ QUOTENAME(Name) from Categories;
-- outputs [tech],[class]

print REPLACE(REPLACE(@categories, '[', ''), ']', '')
--outputs: tech,class

set @fields = REPLACE(REPLACE(@categories, '[', 'ISNULL(['), ']', '], ''0'') AS' + SUBSTRING(@categories, CHARINDEX('[', @categories), CHARINDEX(']',@categories) - CHARINDEX('[', @categories) + Len(']')));
print @fields;
--outputs: ISNULL([tech], 0),ISNULL([class], 0)
```

What I want to know is, is it possible to change the query or should I go to the while-loop fashion for a solution?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This feels like an XY Problem. Why are you injecting column names in the first place?

Comment: I haven't gotten past the CSV part.  Why are you storing such CSV data in your SQL tables?

Comment: Because the column names are pivoted from another table. However since pivoting these columns makes it so there are null values I needed a dynamic null check.

Comment: You'd have to show us how you dynamically generate the SQL you have in order for anyone to help you modify it.

Comment: You would do it the same way you are generating the null checks - however that is, you have kept that secret.

Comment: I would move away from the solution you are using, to store all the delimited column names in a variable. Create the entire dynamic statement in one go. Also don't use that method of creating delimited results, use `STRING_AGG` or the `FOR XML PATH` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could replace what you have with something as simple as the following

```
declare @fields nvarchar(max)

select @fields=Coalesce(@fields+',','') + 'IsNull(' + QuoteName(name) + ',0) as ' + QuoteName(name)
from categories
```

Comment: Aggregation via variable is unsafe and not guaranteed to work properly

Answer (score 1):

As we don't have the full SQL, I can't give you a full solution, however **assuming** you are on a fully supported version of SQL Server, then I would suggest you do something like this:

```sql
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX),
        @CRLF nchar(2) = NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10);

DECLARE @Delimiter nvarchar(50) = @CRLF + N'       '

SET @SQL = N'SELECT {Columns?}' + @CRLF + 
           N'       ' + (SELECT STRING_AGG(N'ISNULL(' + QUOTENAME(C.[Name]) + N',0) AS ' + QUOTENAME(C.[Name]),@Delimiter)
                         FROM dbo.Categories) + @CRLF +
           N'FROM dbo.YourTable' + @CRLF +
           N'WHERE...;';
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL /*N'Parameters?', @Parameters?*/;
```

If you aren't using a fully supported version of SQL Server, then you'll need to use the "old" `FOR XML PATH` method.